# I need to connect a client TCP created in java with a HTTP servant created with node.js

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, tcp

I need to connect a client TCP created in java with a HTTP server created with node.js
I want that on having done click on a button of my HTML an operation executes in the client java via sockets using the module net.

My code HTML:

```
<body>
   <button id="bt1">Button 1</button>
   <button id="bt2">Button 2</button>
   <button id="bt3">Button 3</button>
   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script>
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
            socket.on('httpServer', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('tcp', "For TCP");
      });
   </script>
</body>
```

My code java client:

```
class ClientSocket{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String address = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 5555;             

        try {
          Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);

          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
          String ope = in.readLine();

          if(ope.equals("1")){
              System.out.println("You pulsated on the button 1");
          }else if(ope.equals("2")){
              System.out.println("You pulsated on the button 2");
          }else if(ope.equals("3")){
              System.out.println("You pulsated on the button 3");
          }
          // ........

          in.close();
          socket.close();

        }catch( IOException e){
          System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My code node serverTCP.js:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 5555;

var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(PORT, HOST);

server.on('connection', function(sock) {
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);
    sock.write("TCP sending message : 1");  // No send
    console.log('Server listening on ' + server.address().address +':'+ server.address().port);
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

My code node serverHTTP.js:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(httpHandler), fs = require("fs"), wsock = require('socket.io').listen(http), tcpsock = require('net');

var http_port = 8080;

var tcp_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var tcp_PORT = 5555;

/**
 * http server
 */
function httpHandler (req, res){
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function(err, data) {
    if(err){
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

http.listen(http_port);
console.info("HTTP server listening on " + http_port);

wsock.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ 

    var tcpClient = new tcpsock.Socket({allowHalfOpen: false, readable: true, writable: true});
    tcpClient.setEncoding("ascii");
    tcpClient.setKeepAlive(true);

    tcpClient.connect(tcp_PORT, tcp_HOST, function(){
        console.info('CONNECTED TO : ' + tcp_HOST + ':' + tcp_PORT);

        tcpClient.on('data', function(data){
            console.log('DATA: ' + data);
            socket.emit("httpServer", data);
        });

        tcpClient.on('end', function(data){
            console.log('END DATA : ' + data);
        });
    });

    socket.on('tcp-manager', function(message){
        console.log('"tcp" : ' + message);
        return;
    });

    socket.emit("httpServer", "Initial Data");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use a http server for that. Use Tomcat and create a simple Servlet will fix your problem.

Otherwise you need to listen on the port and accept incoming requests using separate tasks. Thats more complex then your sample code. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html